# SQL syntax, Create Table, Advantage Database

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have to create a table in the Advantage Database Architect - the SQL code that I have used before in an older project is (simplified version)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SomacountData"
(
   "Index" AUTOINC,
   "Data" BLOB,
   "Section" INTEGER DEFAULT -1,
   "factor" FLOAT,
   "ThresHold" FLOAT DESCRIPTION "Calculated Threshold",
PRIMARY KEY ("Index") COMPRESS NONE
DESCRIPTION "SomacountData"
LANGUAGE "ANSI Standard" SORT "Default Order"
USER MAJOR VERSION 1
USER MINOR VERSION 4
);
```

In the Architect this appears to be somewhat more involved - suggestions apreciated.

Comment: Please attempt to put requests in the form of a question.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

- `FLOAT` is probably best mapped to `DOUBLE`.
- Setting the DEFAULT and specifying the primary index requires additional `EXECUTE sp_ModifyFieldProperty` statements (see [Documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_sp_modifyfieldproperty.htm))
- I don't think there is a `DESCRIPTION` in ADS.
- `IF NOT EXISTS` can be solved in different ways, if you have a dictionary you can query the `system.tables` internal table of the dictionary. If you don't you can just ignore the creation error by using `TRY CREATE TABLE ... CATCH ALL END TRY`.

If you have any specific question you should create a new question on SO.

UPDATE:

You can also use the integrated table designer and dump the table code to SQL, but that won't solve your `IF NOT EXISTS` problem.

Comment: you can specify the default and primary key in the table creation using DEFAULT keyword and PRIMARY KEY keywords such as "CREATE TABLE "SomacountData" ("index" autoinc primary key, ...., "section" integer default '-1', ....)"   The DEFAULT value must be a string literal, but it will insert an integer value.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the correction Edgar. The `sp_ModifyFieldProperty` still works and is used by at least the dictionary compare tool to make diff scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your foreign key? Or this is your only table. Foreign keys are crucial in SQL, relational algebra does not work without them. Also i would use more constraints as NOT NULL.

Comment: My problem is the syntax of the Advantage Database SQL - it does not support f.ex the IF NOT EXISTS part. ADS also does not use FLOAT but DOUBLE...